# css help in aligning elements

Tags: html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/yjb7rkck/

Code:

```
<body>
    <div id="parentDiv" style="width:200px;">
        <p style="position:relative;margin-left:0px;">Element1</p>
        <a href="#" style="position:relative;margin-right:0px;">Element2</a>
        <br/>
        <div id="ElementThreeDiv"             style="float:left;height:250px;overflow:auto;">
            <p>Element3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I am trying to achieve the below requirements:

1. All the elements 1,2 & 3 should be in a width of 200px as defined for parent Div
2. Element 1 should be left aligned.
3. Element 2 should be right aligned.
4. Element 3 should be on the next line.

Comment: So what have you tried? BTW I'd avoid inline styling.

Comment: I tried all the options float,position and margin properties

Comment: Stackoverflow isnt a coding service. Please read on how to ask questions. I have code and want CSS written isnt the way to go man.

Comment: Look up CSS selectors, find out how to give your divs classes or ids and use the appropriate selector in css. Then adjust the width and other things you need done. Not really hard with google around.

Comment: @javanoob So what width are you expecting for all three of the elements?

Comment: @divy3993 Element three should occupy full width of 200px.

Comment: And the first two? Also the structure (<p>....</p><a>....</a><div elem3>...</div>) should be maintained?

Comment: @divy3993 Just left and right aligned in a width of 200px.

Comment: Also the structure (<p>....</p><a>....</a><div elem3>...</div>) inside elem1 should be maintained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. Float the first left, the second right, and clear the third. I added the background and overflow on the container to see it more clearly.

```
#parentDiv p {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
}

#parentDiv a {
    float:right;
}

#parentDiv div {
    clear:both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yjb7rkck/5/)**